# HttpListener working on local network, but not externally

Tags: networking

I am attempting to spin up an application that listens on a port and responds to HTTP requests.  I am on a Windows 8 machine connecting through a Netgear router that provides port forwarding.  I have:

- modified my DNS zone file of one of my domains to point to the IP address that is assigned to my cable modem
- Added a port-forwarding rule to my router that sends requests to port 8080 to port 8081 on my computer
- Opened port 8081 on my Windows Firewall
- Executed netsh http add urlact http://+:8081/ user=Everyone listen=yes as administrator
- Started up my app which uses the simple webserver solution found at http://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server.aspx which uses an HttpListener object with a prefix of http://+:8081/.

From any machine on my *local network*, I can browse to http://home.example.com:8080/blah/blah and everything works great.  Whenever I attempt the same URL from a machine connected elsewhere on the Internet, the connection times out.  I have tried using the IP address instead the domain name, and have tried disabling my Windows Firewall (temporarily), still with no luck.

I'm sure this is more of a network setup issue than a code issue, but I thought I would ask anyway to see if there is anything I can do.  Sorry for the spaces in the urls above.  This is my first post to SO, and I apparently don't have enough of a reputation to post more than a single link.

Answer (score -1):

By "elsewhere on the Internet", I am assuming you are attempting to access it from a different ISP.

The thing about some ISPs is that unless you are paying for a "business class" connection, they will do all sorts of tricks to ensure that you remain a "consumer". What you need is an unNATed static IP address.

By this I mean that the IP address that you may have at your home may not be accessible to the outside world because the ISP is actually NATing (or other) that address to you. This is a fairly common practice because of limited IP4 addresses. If you really want a service accessible via the WWW, I would suggest moving your product to a VPN, or at least a commodity hosting provider.

Edit: Try a VPN service like [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/)

Comment: A comment about the downvote reason would be appreciated so I could explain any gaps or misunderstanding.